# Using blob properties in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to save some binary data coming from post request. I'm doing:

```
obj.data=self.request.get('data')
```

And having the error: "Blob() argument should be str instance, not unicod"

I'm trying:

```
obj.data=str(self.request.get('data'))
```

And having: "ascii' codec can't encode character ...". What am I doing wrong? How to save raw data from request?

Answer (score 1):

If you have binary data it's usually http post. I use a form class to save a submitted form to an entity:

```
data = AForm(data=self.request.POST)
entity = data.save(commit=False)
```

Comment: Is it django? I use webapp+appengine. However could you please post the AForm class definition?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using base64 enconding for the parameter.

Comment: This isn't a solution, but rather a workaround. Why are you trying to store text in a blob property in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a blob property, but attempting to store text in it, not raw bytes. You probably want to use a TextProperty, instead.